# Movie involving two children who find an old Victorian-era photograph in their house and are transported back in time

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel

I'm looking for a movie from either the late '80s or '90s that I saw as a child.

I don’t recall the name, but it's about two children (a brother and sister I believe) in the modern day, who find a hidden room in their house (possibly the cellar) and they find a stash of old objects there.

Among the objects is an old Victorian-era photograph of a handsome young man (who may have been an ancestor??) and they are somehow transported back in time to the man in the photo's house. He thinks they broke in but ends up taking care of them, I think something bad happens to the man???

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Amazing_Mr._Blunden (1972)?

Comment: I've edited your question a little by putting some paragraphs in.  Welcome to the site hopefully we can answer your question (and any others you may have).